# Python-String from dictonary in more readable form

Tags: python-3.x

I want to read and save a dictionary to a file. The problem is that `str(dict)` returns one line not very human-readable if the dictionary is large, like this:

```
{"category1": {"one": ["hello", [0, 1, 2, 3]], "two": ["world", [3, 2, 1, 0]]}, "category2": {"one": ["lol", [0, 1, 2, 3]], "two": ["1234", [3, 2, 1, 0]]}}
```

My code reads the file, saves dictionary to variable usuing `eval(string)`, makes changes, converts dictionary to string and saves it back to the same file.
At the beginning the file contained this string:

```
{
    "category1": {
        "one": ["hello", [0, 1, 2, 3]],
        "two": ["world", [3, 2, 1, 0]]
    },

    "category2": {
        "one": ["lol", [0, 1, 2, 3]],
        "two": ["1234", [3, 2, 1, 0]]
    }
}
```

Is there any way making a string from dictionary in simmilar form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import json

d = {"category1": {"one": ["hello", [0, 1, 2, 3]], "two": ["world", [3, 2, 1, 0]]}, "category2": {"one": ["lol", [0, 1, 2, 3]], "two": ["1234", [3, 2, 1, 0]]}}

with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(d, f, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

So two things. I wouldn't use eval() to load a json string. Eval can be unstable and dangerous to use. I would instead do this:

```
import json
jsonvar = json.loads(jsonstring)
```

And then to style it nice and convert it back to a string to write to a file I would do this:

```
import json
jsonvar = json.dumps(jsonvar, indent=4)
```

If you get an error while trying to import json, install it with `pip install json`